# ElasticSearch writing query for priority search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I am new to elastisearch and I just set it up and tried default search. I am using elasticsearch rails gem. I need to write custom query with priority search (some fields in table are more important then others, etc. title, updated_at in last 6 months...). I tried to find explanation or tutorial for how to do this but nothing seems understandable. Can anyone help me with this, soon better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never having used the ruby/elasticsearch integration, it doesn't seem too hard... The docs [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/ruby-api/current/_the_ruby_client.html) show that you'd want to do something like this:

```
client.search index: 'my-index', body: { query: { match: { title: 'test' } } }
```

To do a basic search.

The ES documentation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) shows how to do a field boosted query:

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "this is a test",
    "fields" : [ "subject^3", "message" ] 
  }
}
```

Putting it all together, you'd do something like this:

```
client.search index: 'my-index', body: { query: { multi_match : {
    query : "this is a test",
    fields : [ "subject^3", "message" ] 
  } } }
```

That will allow you to search/boost on fields -- in the above case, the subject field is given 3 times the score of the message field.

There is a very good [blog post](http://jontai.me/blog/2013/01/advanced-scoring-in-elasticsearch/) about how to do advanced scoring.  Part of it shows an example of adjusting the score based on a date:

```
...
     "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "date"
        }
      },
      "script": "(0.08 / ((3.16*pow(10,-11)) * abs(now - doc['date'].date.getMillis()) + 0.05)) + 1.0"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done in php, Never used the gem from Ruby on rails. Here you can give the priority for the fields using the caret (^) notation.

Example:- Suppose if we have fields namely name, email, message and address in table and the priority should be given for the name and message then you can write as below

```
> {   "multi_match" : {
>     "query" : "this is a test",
>     "fields" : [ "name^3", "message^2".... ]    } }
```

Here name has 3 times higher priority than other fields and message has got 2 times higher priority than other fields.